Could Bragg mirrors be used to make a cavity for gravitons?
A line of experiments that probes the quantum mechanical nature of light has been to use optical cavities, which greatly enhance light-matter interactions. Is it in principle possible to do the same thing with gravitational waves?
Thinking through this possibility a bit, a single layer of material surely interacts with gravational waves too weakly to act as a mirror. But a Bragg mirror might work; equally spaced layers of material, each weakly reflecting an incident gravitational wave, could create constructive interference, enhancing the reflection coefficient. However one also needs to consider absorption by the mirrors, so it's not obvious that achieving a high refection coefficient is possible even in principle.
In all likelihood the cavity would have to be astronomically large, but that's OK. This is just a hypothetical question.

In principle yes (gravitational waves aren't fundamentally that different from any other sort of wave), but in practice you'd probably need a system of mirrors larger than the solar system for this to work... gravitational waves can pass through the whole Earth with negligible decrease in amplitude.

It's not obvious to me that the reflection coefficient could be made large. If each layer absorbs much more than it reflects, then the Bragg mirror won't work. That's why I emphasize absorption in the question.
